# Cannot install application insights to project

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-2015

working on a SPA using angular 1.4.8, .net framework 4.5.2 MVC

Getting error below when trying to install application insight with azure

Failed to install pacakage microsoft.Applicationinshights.Web with error
angularJs.core

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens in our tool sometimes when Nuget tries to validate the entire dependency tree of your solution, but using only the location where our nuget packages are located to validate them.  So it can't find angularjs.core in our directory (because it isn't there, only our stuff is there :( )

If "try, try again" doesn't work for you, as it seems to be a timing issue, the workaround is to nstall the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web` nuget package into your project using the standard nuget tools in VS.  (if you also install `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Javascript` package, when you right click the project you should be able to find a "configure application insights" item instead of an "Add application insights" item in the context menu, and you can use that to set your resource, etc.

aside: I've been working on getting setting in the nuget installer api calls for "install *this* package from this location, but validate all the other packages from all the other sources" but so far, I haven't gotten much traction from them.

Comment: what i ended up doing was setting up my project in new work space in new machine and it worked.